# UIPanGesture recognizer swiping only in one direction

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9, uipangesturerecognizer

I am working on UIPanGestureRecognizer and to me it is working. but I have some problem here as I am new to iOS and just shifted from Android to iOS. 
First take a look at what I want to do:

**What I want:** I have a UITableView and I want to perform swiping on the Cells. I just want to drag them from left to right side and move/Delete that cell. Pretty same like it is done in android.

But I just want to move the item only in one direction. And that is "LEFT TO RIGHT". But not from right to left. Now here take a look at what I have done so far

**What I have Done:**

```
    @objc func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // 1
    if recognizer.state == .began {
        // when the gesture begins, record the current center location
        originalCenter = center
        print("Center",originalCenter)

    }
    // 2
    if recognizer.state == .changed {
        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self)


        center = CGPoint(x: originalCenter.x+translation.x, y: originalCenter.y)

        // has the user dragged the item far enough to initiate a delete/complete?
        deleteOnDragRelease = frame.origin.x < -frame.size.width / 2.0
        completeOnDragRelease = frame.origin.x > frame.size.width / 2.0
        // print ("FrameX = ",frame.origin.x , " , ","Width = ",frame.size.width / 2.0 , "Total = ",frame.origin.x < -frame.size.width / 2.0 )
        //print ("DelOnDrag = ",deleteOnDragRelease , " , ","CompOnDrag = ",completeOnDragRelease)

    }
    // 3
    if recognizer.state == .ended {
        // the frame this cell had before user dragged it
        let originalFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.origin.y,
                                   width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
        if deleteOnDragRelease {
            if delegate != nil && clickedItem != nil {
                // notify the delegate that this item should be deleted
                delegate!.toDoItemDeleted(clickedItem: clickedItem!)
            }
        } else if completeOnDragRelease {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 8.2, animations: {self.frame = originalFrame})
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 8.2, animations: {self.frame = originalFrame})
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can make a check on ".changed" , and calculate if the X value is going towards 0 or lesser then 0. But point is for some time it will move item from right to left.

**Question:**  Is there any way I can get the x value of point of contact? or just some how I can get user want to swipe right to left and just stop user from doing that?? Please share your knowledge

Comment: You should try to use [UISwipeGesture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizer) instead of UIPanGesture

Comment: why I should use this ?

Comment: just give me its example , or tutorial

Comment: @QuocNguyen is right you have to perform Uiswipegesture on uitableviewcell and you don't need any cgpoint just use delegates method that swap gesture.direction == right then perform your task

Comment: Yes I saw this method looks better, but can you change my code and let me know how to animate view with user swipe until the gesture crosses the half of the width of the item width ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya can you please tell me how to get the current value of x ?

Comment: Write this code on swap gesture delegates method if sendview.frame.origin.x > sendview.frame.size.width - 42 { // your cell swap until your cell end and perform your task }

Comment: and if you want to do with pan gesture then follow this https://www.raywenderlich.com/2153-how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-1-2

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya yes I am following that tutorial and I am using the Pangesture. but problem is it does move both ways, what should I do to get only left to right swipe using pangesture

Comment: @Androidteem just follow my answer and your problem solve.

Comment: And yes if your problem solve by my answer then  you can approve my answer so other user get help easily. thank you

Comment: thanks @HimanshuMoradiya that was great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your same code just one changes in your UIGestureRecognizer method replace with this code and your problem solve. only left to right side swap work on your tableview cell . any query regrading this just drop comment below.

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if let panGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
            let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: superview!)
            if translation.x >=  0 {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
        return false
    }
```

**Good Luck.**

**Keep coding.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below extensions

```
extension UIPanGestureRecognizer {

    enum GestureDirection {
        case Up
        case Down
        case Left
        case Right
    }

    func verticalDirection(target: UIView) -> GestureDirection {
        return self.velocity(in: target).y > 0 ? .Down : .Up
    }

    func horizontalDirection(target: UIView) -> GestureDirection {
        return self.velocity(in: target).x > 0 ? .Right : .Left
    }   
}
```

And you can get direction like below

```
gestureRecognizer.horizontalDirection(target: self)
```

Comment: its not helpful. as I just want to check if the movement is the left to right or the right to left in horizontal. 
the idea u presented I have implemented it in more compact way